# Connecting to FTP server in Android

Tags: java, android, ftp

Im new to android programming. Im trying to build a basic app whice tries to connect to an ftp server. I have no problems connecting to the server in other ways. I hope you guys could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                          String password, int port) {
    try {
        client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect(InetAddress.getByName(host), 21);

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())) {
            boolean status = client.login(username, password);
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            return status;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host);
    }
    return false;
}
```

the function is called from my main activity `OnCreate()` method.
When I run I just recieve the "could not connect to host" tag.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to print the stacktrace in the `catch` block - with `e.printStackTrace()` - but I would guess that you're getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Your'e right! how can I fix that, a search showed me AsyncTask but Im not sure how to use it